# Insert Integer into img src

Tags: html, jsp

I have this line of code:

```
<p><img src="/Hangman/img/hangman-0.png" /></p>
```

So instead of hangman-0.png I want to use an integer like this:

```
<p><img src="/Hangman/img/hangman-INTEGER.png" /></p>
```

How can I put the integer value where I stated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uh, just `<p><img src="/Hangman/img/hangman-${bean.imageId}.png" /></p>`? Or isn't that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this(BalusC comment is good enough):-

```
<p><img src="/Hangman/img/hangman-${bean.imageId}.png" /></p>
```